# Trouble converting .htaccess rewrite rules for nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rewrite

Hi all I am trying to convert the following .htaccess  code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^arrowchat/chatroom ^/chatroom/ [L] 
RewriteRule ^arrowchat/cron ^/cron/ [L] 
RewriteRule ^arrowchat/debug ^/debug/ [L] 
RewriteRule ^arrowchat/list ^/list/ [L] 
RewriteRule ^arrowchat/mobile ^/mobile/ [L] 
RewriteRule ^arrowchat/popout ^/popout/ [L] 
RewriteRule ^arrowchat/video ^/video/ [L] 
</IfModule>
```

This is what I came up with

```
if ($rule_0 = "2"){
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/chatroom ^/chatroom/ last;
}
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/cron ^/cron/ last;
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/debug ^/debug/ last;
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/list ^/list/ last;
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/mobile ^/mobile/ last;
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/popout ^/popout/ last;
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/video ^/video/ last;
```

On trying to reload the nginx conf files by running the command **nginx -s  reload** I am getting an error msg

```
nginx: [emrg] unknown "rule_0" variable
```

My current default.conf file for nginx looks like this

```
#
# The default server
#
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  jukpac.com;
    return       301 http://www.jukpac.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.jukpac.com;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
if ($rule_0 = "2"){
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/chatroom ^/chatroom/ last;
}
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/cron ^/cron/ last;
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/debug ^/debug/ last;
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/list ^/list/ last;
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/mobile ^/mobile/ last;
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/popout ^/popout/ last;
    rewrite ^/arrowchat/video ^/video/ last;
     }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|swf)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    } 
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Can anyone help me out a bit with the rewrite rules?

Comment: I think I saw this question on stackoverflow a couple of days ago, I think your whole config needs few things, like what's the main `root` for the wesbite? and whats `/arrowchat` is it required in the URL ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I am struggling with this issue for a month now, no one seems to answer me :( I would be happy to answer whatever details you need in the hopes that I can get this running. The main root for the site is `/usr/share/nginx/html` and `/arrowchat` is the folder inside which the `arrowchat` files are located and it is required in the url

Comment: Is it what YOU want? or is it there because that's just how you found it works ? do you have a domain name ? or is it a localhost project

Comment: It has a domain name www.jukpac.com I was using it earlier in an apache based VPS I would login using the link `www.jukpac.com/arrowchat/admin` but now when I try it doesn;t work properly the static files don't load, sometimes if i try to open the file 'www.jukpac.com/arrowchat/admin/css/index.html' I get a 404 error even though I can use FTP and see that the index.html file is right there. I am tweaking with the .conf files and sometimes i can make something work but something else crashes. I need the correct and complete rules

Comment: what does the main domain go to? is there another site that's hosted on that? without the `/arrowchat`, and if it is, is it still on apache

Comment: No it is not on apache anymore it runs on nginx and PHP-FPM the main domain goes to `/usr/share/nginx/html` There are no other sites hosted in the VPS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12314/discussion-between-mohammad-abushady-and-rick-roy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna remove some unnecessary stuff and clean the rest for your `default.conf`, try this and reload nginx and tell me if it works.

```
server { #redirecting server
    listen       80;
    server_name  jukpac.com;
    return       301 http://www.jukpac.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.jukpac.com;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html; #move the root to server level
    index  index.php # move index to server level
    error_page  404  /404.html;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|swf)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    } 

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```